# Is my program CPU bound or IO bound when dealing with subprocesses?

Tags: python, multithreading, console, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

Using Python, I am trying to figure out if I should use `multiprocessing`, `threading`, or `asyncio`, and the first step is to figure out if my program is CPU bound or IO bound.

The slowest part of my code is interacting with a subprocess that was created prior to the asyncronous programming. The relevant code is as follows:

```
    # First curl command to existing JS console running on my machine
    curl_command = <curl command here>
    cmd = shlex.split(curl_command)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

    # Different curl command
    self.other_command = self._other_curl_command()

    # Interact with an existing JS console running on my machine
    output_one = call_one()
    output_two = call_two()
    output_three = call_three()
```

It is important to note that these calls are to a JS console I have running on my machine. Are these I/O bound activities? If so, should I be using `threading`/`asyncio`?

Comment: It is hard to tell what this code does. The return value of `subprocess.Popen()` is not retained in a variable. What do `call_one()` and other functions do?